# Iphone-x responsive issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

How to solve iphone-x responsive issues. Issue only showing in real device. How can i solve this?
The problem is that when I use chrome responsive view the website looks good and responsive on all devices. However when I go to it with safari on an iphone. The website is not responsive anymore.

Comment: you need to provide iphone-x to each user who want to answer this question.

Comment: @AmanSharma you are right :)

Comment: Some of the CSS styles doesn't work with Safari. You will have to address each issue seperately.

Comment: There’s no code in your question whatsoever: please see how to create an [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score -1):

You would need to provide a better description of the issue you're facing. The reason you see such a big difference is in general the way iOS and Safari operate, as they differ from Chrome's Dev Tools.

What you can do is use tools like [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/), which emulate your website on real devices, making them 100% accurate. I do however think the website has to be on an actual server before using this tool.